# Change node shape in NetworkX according to node attribute

Tags: python, visualization, networkx

I am mapping a network where I want to display nodes as different shapes according to a node attribute (labelled 'POS' with variables 'Member', 'Leader' and 'Associate'). Here is a sample of my node data:

`[('ALICE DIAMOND', {'Total': 19, 'OP': 19, 'POS': 'Leader'}), ('LOUISA NEAL', {'Total': 1, 'OP': 1, 'POS': 'Associate'}), ('DOROTHY MAYS', {'Total': 6, 'OP': 13, 'POS': 'Member'})`

I have created the network and added the nodes and edges. I have drawn the network but am unable to change the shape based on node attribute. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Here is the current state of my code:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, 'P1', 'P2', 'YEARS')
nodes = pd.read_csv('nodelist_all.csv')
nodes2 = nodes[['N', 'Total', 'OP', 'POS']]
data = nodes2.set_index('N').to_dict('index').items()
G.add_nodes_from(data)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_size=30)
```